# Java Compile-Time Type Checking For Polymorphic Collections

Tags: java, generics, type-safety

I'm trying to write a collection that's 100% type safe. I have it all working properly the only issue I'm struggling with is this.

```
    AttributeMap map = new AttributeMap();

    map.put("special", 100);

    map.put("running", false);

    int special = map.get("special");   

    boolean running = map.get("running");

    System.out.println("special value: " + special + " running value: " + running); 

    // not caught at compilation time, caught at run-time
    boolean test = map.get("special");

    // caught at compilation time
    boolean test2 = map.get("special", Integer.class);
```

Output without the run-time error

```
special value: 100 running value: false
```

The value from the map becomes the value I choose. Example special should be a type integer, because that's what I put into the map is there a way to check this error at compile-time so it doesn't become a run-time error?

Before I post this code, this is going to look overly complicated you may ask why not just do this?

```
    private Map<Object, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>();
```

Yes that would do the same as what I'm doing, but that fails to catch every cast at compilation time. I'm trying to keep track of my type I put in as a value and retrieve it as the same type so it can be caught at compilation time.

Here's my class so far.

AttributeMap

```
package com.vltr.collection.attr;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;

/**
* A specialized {@link Map} that ensures type safely upon a generic map.
* 
* @author Vult-R
*/
public final class AttributeMap {

/**
 * The map contains attributes.
 */
private Map<AttributeKey<?, ?>, Object> attributes;

private Set<AttributeKey<?, ?>> set = new HashSet<>();

/**
 * Creates a new {@link AttributeMap}.
 * 
 * @param attributes
 *            The map of attributes.
 */
public AttributeMap(Map<AttributeKey<?, ?>, Object> attributes) {
    this.attributes = attributes;
}

/**
 * Creates an empty {@link AttributeMap}.
 */
public AttributeMap() {
    this.attributes = new HashMap<AttributeKey<?, ?>, Object>();
}

/**
 * Places a new {@link AttributeKey} into the map.
 * 
 * @param key
 *            The key to be used.
 * 
 * @param value
 *            The value to map.
 * 
 * @param clazz
 *            The class type associated between the key and value.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <K, V> void put(K key, V value) {
    put(new AttributeKey<K, V>(key, (Class<V>) value.getClass()), value);
}

/**
 * A wrapper function for placing a new {@link AttributeKey} into the map.
 * 
 * @param key
 *            The key to be used.
 * 
 * @param value
 *            The value to map.
 * 
 * @param clazz
 *            The class type associated between the key and value.
 */
private <K, V> void put(AttributeKey<K, V> key, V value) {
    attributes.put(key, value);
    set.add(key);
}

/**
 * A wrapper function for retrieving a value.
 * 
 * @param key
 *            The key mapped to a value.
 * 
 * @throws AttributeException
 *             If an error occurs while trying to retrieve a value.
 * 
 * @return The associated value.
 */
private <K, V> V get(AttributeKey<K, V> key) throws AttributeException {

    V type = null;

    AttributeKey<K, V> k = getFromSet(key);

    try {
        type = (V) key.getClazz().cast(attributes.get(key));
    } catch (ClassCastException ex) {
        throw new AttributeException(key, attributes.get(key).getClass());
    }

    if (key.getClazz() != k.getClazz()) {
        System.out.println("not the same");         
    }

    return type;

}

/**
 * Gets a value for retrieving a value
 * 
 * @param key
 *            The key mapped to a value.
 * 
 * @param clazz
 *            The class type associated between the key and value.
 * 
 * @throws AttributeException
 *             If an error occurs while trying to retrieve a value.
 * 
 * @return The associated value.
 */
public <K, V> V get(K key, Class<V> clazz) {
    return get(new AttributeKey<K, V>(key, clazz));
}

/**
 * Gets a value for retrieving a value
 * 
 * @param key
 *            The key mapped to a value.
 * 
 * @param clazz
 *            The class type associated between the key and value.
 * 
 * @throws AttributeException
 *             If an error occurs while trying to retrieve a value.
 * 
 * @return The associated value.
 */
public <K, V> V get(K key) {

    final AttributeKey<K, V> k = new AttributeKey<K, V>(key, getFromSet(new AttributeKey<K, V>(key, null)).getClazz());

    return get(k);
}

/**
 * Removes a {@code key} and associated value from the map.
 * 
 * @param key
 *            The key and its associated value to remove.
 */
public <K, V> void remove(AttributeKey<K, V> key) {
    attributes.remove(key);
    set.remove(key);
}
```

AttributeKey

```
/**
 * Removes a {@code key} and associated value from the map.
 * 
 * @param key
 *            The key and its associated value to remove.
 */
public <K, V> void remove(K key) {

    final AttributeKey<K, V> ak = new AttributeKey<K, V>(key, getFromSet(new AttributeKey<K, V>(key, null)).getClazz());

    remove(ak);
}

/**
 * Sets a {@code key} and its associated {@code value}.
 * 
 * @param key
 *            The key to set.
 * 
 * @param value
 *            The value to set.
 */
public <K, V> void set(AttributeKey<K, V> key, V value) {
    attributes.put(key, value);
}

/**
 * Clears all keys and associated values from this map.
 */
public void clear() {
    attributes.clear();
}

/**
 * Determines if a {@code key} with associated {@code clazz} type exists
 * within this map.
 * 
 * @param key
 *            The key to check.
 * 
 * @param clazz
 *            The clazz to check.
 * 
 * @return {@code true} If this map contains a specified key and its correct
 *         class type. {@code false} Otherwise.
 */
public <K, V> boolean containsKey(K key, Class<V> clazz) {
    return attributes.containsKey(new AttributeKey<K, V>(key, clazz));
}

/**
 * Determines if a value exists within this map.
 * 
 * @param value
 *            The value to check.
 * 
 * @return {@code true} If this map contains this specified value.
 *         {@code false} Otherwise.
 */
public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
    return attributes.containsValue(value);
}

/**
 * Retrieves the undlying {@link #entrySet()} from this map.
 * 
 * @return The {@link #entrySet()}.
 */
public Set<Entry<AttributeKey<?, ?>, Object>> entrySet() {
    return attributes.entrySet();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private <K, V> AttributeKey<K, V> getFromSet(AttributeKey<K, V> key) {
    for(AttributeKey<?, ?> k : set) {
        if (k.getKey() == key.getKey()) {
            return (AttributeKey<K, V>) k;
        }           
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Determines if this attribute map equals another attribute map.
 * 
 * @param o
 *            The object to check.
 * 
 * @return {@code true} If this map equals another attribute set,
 *         {@code false} Otherwise. *
 */
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return attributes.equals(o);
}

/**
 * Retrieves the hash code for this attribute map.
 * 
 * @return The hash code.
 */
public int hashCode() {
    return attributes.hashCode();
}

/**
 * Determines if this attribute map is empty.
 * 
 * @return {@true} If this map is empty, {@code false} Otherwise.
 */
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return attributes.isEmpty();
}

/**
 * Retrieves the underlying {@link #keySet()} from this map.
 * 
 * @return The {@link #keySet()}.
 */
public Set<AttributeKey<?, ?>> keySet() {
    return attributes.keySet();
}

/**
 * Gets the size of this map.
 * 
 * @return The size.
 */
public int size() {
    return attributes.size();
}

public int setSize() {
    return set.size();
}

/**
 * Gets the values of this map.
 * 
 * @return The values.
 */
public Collection<Object> values() {
    return attributes.values();
}

}


package com.vltr.collection.attr;

/**
 * Represents a wrapper that wraps a {@link Map}s key value. This class will       help enforce the correct type.
 * 
 * @author Vult-R
 */
public final class AttributeKey<K, V> {

/**
 * The key that will be used.
 */
private final K key;

/**
 * The class type associated with this key.
 */
private final Class<V> clazz;

/**
 * Creates a new {@link AttributeKey}.
 * 
 * @param key
 *      The key that will be used.
 * 
 * @param clazz
 *      The associated class type.
 */
public AttributeKey(K key, Class<V> clazz) {
    this.key = key;
    this.clazz = clazz;
}   

/**
 * Gets the key for this attribute.
 * 
 * @return The key.
 */
public K getKey() {
    return key;
}

/**
 * Gets the associated class type for this attribute.
 * 
 * @return The class type.
 */
public Class<V> getClazz() {
    return clazz;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((key == null) ? 0 : key.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    AttributeKey<?, ?> other = (AttributeKey<?, ?>) obj;
    if (key == null) {
        if (other.key != null) {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (!key.equals(other.key)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return key.getClass().getSimpleName();
}
}

package com.vltr.collection.attr;

/**
 * The {@link RuntimeException} implementation specifically for {@link    Attribute}s.
 *
 * @author Seven
 */
public final class AttributeException extends RuntimeException {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * Creates a new {@link AttributeException}.
 *
 * @param key
 *    The key or this attribute.
 *
 * @param value
 *    The value for this attribute.
 */
public AttributeException(AttributeKey<?, ?> key, Object value) {
    super(String.format("Invalid value type: %s for [key=%s], only accepts type of %s", value.getClass().getSimpleName(), key.getKey().toString(), key.getClazz().getClass().getSimpleName()));
}

/**
 * Creates a new {@link AttributeException}.
 * 
 * @param key
 *      The key which contains an error.
 */
    public AttributeException(AttributeKey<?, ?> key) {
    super(String.format("Could not retrieve a value for [key= %s]",   key.getKey()));
    }

    public AttributeException(AttributeKey<?, ?> key, Class<?> clazz) {
    super(String.format("Could not cast [key= %s] from [type= %s] to [type=   %s]. ", key.getKey(), key.getClazz().getSimpleName(), clazz.getSimpleName()));
    }

}
```

I can catch this problem by doing this.

```
        map.put("special", 100);

    // correct
    int special = map.get("special", Integer.class);

    // incorrect and caught at compile-time     
    boolean special = map.get("special", Integer.class);
```

Though I don't want to specify the second parameter I want to hide that. Is that possible?

Comment: Can you post the code for AttributeKey as well ?

Comment: Yeah I just did that.

Comment: @SameerNaik google for auto-boxing

Comment: @Jim Garrison Yeah I'm not sure how to avoid that.

Comment: Your code is throwing NullpointerException on line  boolean test = map.get("special");   because previously you have removed the "special" key and inside the get method it is doing getFromSet(new AttributeKey<K, V>(key, null)).getClazz()  so it try to getClazz of NULL.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov boolean test = map.get("special"); is the wrong type, I'm trying to catch that before you can run it.

Comment: You can't do it. The only way to get full compile-time type safety, where `special` is an integer value and `running` is a boolean value, is to create a class. That's what they are for. I mean, for the compiler to do type-checking, you have to declare, in a way the compiler understands, what the type of `special` and `running` is. With a generic map, you can't define that. With a class, you can.

Comment: generics are checked at compile time and are ignored at run time ..
now in `Map` everything is ignored at compile time because they don't specify any type and they are available to run `legacy code` but now `Map<K,V>` is recommended to provide type safety ....for more info you can read a book on this topic `Java Generics and Collections By Philip Wadler, Maurice Naftalin`

Comment: You could replace the string key with something with a type parameter so the type info gets there automatically.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for the info. I was trying to create wrapper classes that would hold its type so it could be checked at compile-time.

Comment: @asteriskNinja Interesting, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @JimmyT. I tried that that's why I'm using an AttributeKey because it has a type parameter. I was also trying to provide type-safety for magic strings.

Comment: @ChadAdams You have to use AttributeKey in get and put. Otherwise it won't workm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this.

Java does not support compile-time type checking for polymorphic generic collections.  You can add anything to a `Collection<?>` but when retrieving you always get back `Object` and have to cast to the appropriate type, which will always involve a runtime check.

The compiler was trying to tell you this but you disabled the warnings with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`, which is like putting black tape over the temperature warning light in your car and then being surprised when the engine overheats.

You say:

> I can catch this problem by doing this.
>
> ```
> map.put("special", 100);
> // correct
> int special = map.get("special", Integer.class);
>
> // incorrect and caught at compile-time     
> boolean special = map.get("special", Integer.class);
> ```
>
> Though I don't want to specify the second parameter I want to hide that. Is that possible?

Think this through.  The `put` calls could (will) have happened far, far away (i.e. not in the current source file, possibly something compiled last year).  The ***compiler*** has no idea what types are contained in the `Map` ***at runtime*** for any specific key. In fact on two different executions a given key could map to values of completely different types.  How is the compiler, when it is compiling the source, supposed to know the value type associated with a key ***in the future***? Or that the type will always be the same one?

From a comment by the OP:

> Though making 100% type-safe collections using a map is possible. See here https://github.com/atomicint/aj8/tree/master/server/src/main/java/org/apollo/game/attribute

Notice in `AttributeMap.java`:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")  
public <T> T get(AttributeKey<T> key) { 
    ...
```

All that code does is push the runtime check into `AttributeMap<>#get()`, and it also resorts to `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.  It just hides the runtime check so your code doesn't have to hide it.  The runtime check and potential `ClassCastException` are still there, and this is most definitely NOT any more type safe.

Comment: Isn't anything possible in programming? I know netty solved this problem by defining extensible enums/ constants.

Comment: Obviously it is possible to programm something that behaves this way, you already did it. You're question is about if a specific syntax is possible in java. Not everything is valid syntax.